# How to play video on mobile browser's webpage WHILE ON the webpage?

Tags: browser, video, adobe-flash, video-streaming

On any browser I try, even with SkyFire 4.0 and Flash, when I play a video on a webpage, what happens is the video is actually played by another program(Moboplayer, SkyFire's client, HTML5 browser video player, etc.).

What I want to do is play a video and watch it streaming while still being able to:

1.Move the webpage around, scroll, navigate, select other buttons, radio boxes, hyperlinks, etc.

2.Be able to have Flash run other streaming media, such as top-bar Flash ads, flash games in the manner described above, etc.

3.Access webpages more like they're intended and viewed on a non-mobile targeted site, but through a mobile device and browser.

Here's a picture to illustrate what I mean crystal clearly:

[image]

What I want to know is what the problem is here:

1.Is it the way the browsers are programmed/configured?

2.Can't a browser app developed for Android/iOS/Windows Phone/Symbian/etc. (theoretically) be used identically with touch gesturization like if with a keyboard(such as pressing articulate little buttons, scrolling iFrames properly, running Flash runtime).

In other words, is it possible for Flash to run like it does on Windows on Android?

Why and why not?

PS: The problem is that on my device I can't find any tricks to get this done right, and I'm very limited with Flash video playback in this manner(and Flash altogether).

**Just to clarify, no, I'm not unaware of the YouTube app. What I want to do is all of the aforementioned tasks (video streaming, viewing Flash ads/animation, etc.) right from a single webpage which the .swf data lies upon(no "transferring" of data to other programs and leaving the webpage).**

Comment: What browser are you using? At least #1 works for me on the LG stock browser (P880), and AFAIR also on my other devices. I cannot tell for #2 (no use for me). For #3 are also solutions available, e.g. switching the browser to desktop mode.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 video plays within the browser in Chrome. To use HTML 5 video with Youtube (both the mobile and desktop websites), go to http://www.youtube.com/html5 to turn it on.

Browsers won't be able to run Flash animations, videos, and games, because Adobe decided to stop supporting Flash on mobile devices. Adobe is also winding down its Flash authoring tools and encouraging its customers to output to HTML 5 instead. Because Flash is a closed, proprietary format, Adobe's free to choose to support or not support Android according to their whims, and there's very little consumers can do about that.